# Proper encoding for umlauts in .csv file

Tags: r, csv, encoding, character-encoding, diacritics

I scraped a site that includes the names of many different cities from around the world using `R`'s `rvest` package. Some of these names have German umlauts and characters from almost every other major language in them which are not showing properly in the .csv file I used to output the text. Is there a way to make Excel display these names properly? I'm using Excel 2011 on Mac. Here is some examples of what the names appear as in my csv file.

"MÃ”Ãˆhldorf am Inn" instead of "Mühldorf am Inn"

"PÃ”_rnu" instead of "Pärnu"

I did not use any kind of encoding when outputting the text as a cvs and don't have access to the original scraped object in R.

`write.csv(data, "master_me_data.csv")`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide [MCVE] and read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html to make question on-topic on SO (and generally good quality).

Comment: What is your locale (`Sys.getlocale()`)? Try different encodings when reading the csv file. You can start with `encoding = "UTF-8"`.